# Maven executing configured plugin

Tags: maven, plugins, configuration, execution

Under Maven version `3.0.4` I have the problem to specify the execution of a single configured plugin. Say I have two different configured maven-antrun-plugins. Both are in the same lifecycle. How can I target the plugin I want to execute without using different lifecycles? 
Since version `3.3.1` it's possible to do it in this form: `mvn groupid:artifactid:goal@id`
Is there a way to do this in a similar way in version 3.0.4 or lower?

Comment: You are talking about to call a plugin goal from command line?

Comment: @khmarbaise yes

Answer (score 0):

You can use the "default-" in your pom to have the first plugin running during the default lifecycle (since Maven 2.2.0), and use a classifier for the second plugin, for example with the maven jar plugin, you can see the example below:

```
<plugin>
   <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
      <executions>
       <execution>
        <id>default-jar</id>
        <configuration>
           <excludes>
              <exclude>**/somepackage/*</exclude>
            </excludes>
        </configuration>
     </execution>
     <execution>
        <id>special-jar</id>
           <phase>package</phase>
           <goals>
              <goal>jar</goal>
           </goals>
        <configuration>
          <includes>
             <include>**/sompackage/*</include>
           </includes>
           <classifier>somepackage</classifier>
         </configuration>
      </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

Comment: You still need to use a different goal on the command line, as  a workaround, as the execution by id was only implemented in 3.3.1, see: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/MNG-5768